# how to run ruby profiler when my script takes CLI arguments

Tags: ruby, profiler

here's how i run my script:

```
ruby script.rb Arg1 [optional-Arg2]
```

how can I run the ruby profiler and send the output to a file?

I've tried this:

```
ruby -r profile script.rb arg1 > out.txt
```

and some quoting mixed in:

```
ruby -r profile "script.rb arg1" > out.txt
```

nothing's worked so far. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: You could use: http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/ which seems to be the preferred tool for profiling (this doesn't answer your question off-course, just offering an alternative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but

```
ruby -r profile script.rb arg1 > out.txt 2>&1
```

Should do. Most likely the profiler prints stuff on the std_error, not on std_out.

Comment: nice! works for me. I tried playing around with the stderr output but I couldn't figure it out obviously.